# Adding multiple data values to ajax data string

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to add my state selection to the city search data so that only cities in the selected state will be selected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
**var state = $("#search-box-state").val();**
       $("#search-box-city").keyup(function(){
            var state = $("#search-box-state").val();
                                      
                                      $.ajax({
                                          type: "POST",
                                          url: "readCity.php",
                                          d**ata:'keyword='+$(this).val()+'state='+state,**
                                          beforeSend: function() {
                                            $("#search-box-city").css("background","FFF");
                                      }, 
                                        success: function(data){
                                          $("#suggesstion-box").show();
                                          $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
                                          $("#search-box-city").css("background","FFF");
                                      }
                        });
            });
  });
function selectCity(val){
    $("#search-box-city").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data fields have to be separated by an `&`

```
data:'keyword='+$(this).val()+'&state='+state,
```

or you can let jQuery serialize it for you by passing a data object

```
data:{keyword: $(this).val(), state: state},
```